# Jupyter Kernel keeps restarting while importing anything such as Numpy or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[image: Screenshot: Kernel automatically restarts while running the block of code with import statements]

```
import numpy as np

#creating a numpy array
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a)
print(type(a))
```

Even in basic code like these, the kernel dies.

I tried doing `conda update --all` and `conda update numpy` but it is still not working.

Comment: How large is the `auto.csv` file you are loading?

Comment: Have you started your jupyter from the command line? If so, can you then add what is printed there?

Comment: Do you have any other open notebooks running? The Jupyter server can only handle so many open notebooks at once. In classic notebook, from the *Running* tab on the notebook homepage, stop any unwanted notebook kernels.